# Use CSS variables in SCSS color map declaration

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass

I am trying to get this to work:

```
:root {
  --primary: #02197f;
}


$colors: (
  primary: var(--primary),
);
```

but the color is not defined when I do this.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

My goal is to be able to dynamically change my SCSS colors by passing it the CSS variable as I change the CSS variable from javascript like `.setProperty('--primary', 'purple');`

Any help would be awesome

Comment: https://codepen.io/jakealbaugh/post/css4-variables-and-sass

Comment: @TJBlackman thanks for the comment but I already read that article and wasn't able to get it to work. Were you successful in getting it to work?

Comment: Can you show us how you're using the colour? Your code seems to work ok for me: https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/3b478126d9531c60326a548e8554a5ed

Comment: Sass is a build-time library. CSS variables are computed at runtime. You can use a sass map to pass the string `var(--primary)` around your stylesheet, but sass can't evaluate that for you, because CSS variables evaluate at runtime.